# Making a character list from a string in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming, character

I am trying to make from a String to a character list. But i have come up with something but I am stuck.

```
compress :: String -> [Char]
compress x = [map head (group x) !! a : []| a <- [0..length x]]
```

The problem is that this makes almost fine, but when i write "apple", it comes with `["a","p","p","l","e"]` not `['a','p','p','l','e']` 
and we all know 
`"apple" /= ["a","p","p","l","e"]`.

But when i try it at the GHCI, but without making a list, it works fine, like:

`map head (group "apple") !! 0` -> `'a'`

But when i try to make a list of these elements, like put every element after each other, it does like this ["a","p","p",...]. 
My question is: Is there a way to make from a String to a list of a character without putting them into " "?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Would you make an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Since `String` is type synonym for `[Char]`, `"apple"` is already the same as `['a','p','p','l','e']`.

Not sure what function are you looking for, but `id :: String -> [Char]` might suffice.

Comment: I know String is a List of a character, but my function makes list of a character list, which is not fine for me.

Comment: @AttilaFodor The point is that *you don't need a function*. A `String` by definition is such a list of characters.

Comment: Maybe i have written it wrong.

I need to make a function which comes with these : ['a','p','p','l','e'], because i have to zip it with an other list.
I know that "apple" = ['a','p','p','l','e']

Comment: @AttilaFodor Curious. What notion of equality do you have in your head for which admitting `"apple" = ['a','p','p','l','e']` does not immediately resolve the question you have? You have the former, you want the latter, and you agree they are equal. So you should be happy, right? Because they are equal, you have the latter, which is what you wanted. You're *already* done.